# Wordpress asks to update a plugin already updated

Tags: plugins, updates

I've just updated a plugin but Wordpress asks to update it again.

But the strange thing is that Wordpress knows the current version of the plugin in question is already the last one.

In fact, it says me something like:

> You are using version 3.4.2. Update to version 3.4.2

The exact same version!

I'm attaching a screenshot (is in Italian, but it is very clear the meaning).

[image]

Any ideas about how to solve this issue?

Comment: That plugin does not appear to be distributed via the plugin directory, so this issue would be with the plugin's own custom update mechanism. You will need to speak to the author.

Comment: Ok, thank you... I thought it was a problem of mine... Then I will drop an email to the author: thank you!